# Number of elements in a set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

i am just getting started with discrete mathematics and set theory and i came across this question which would seem like an elementary problem. I would appreciate any help on this :

Suppose $m$ and $n$ are positive integers with $m < n.$ How many elements does $[m,m+1,\dots,n]$ have?

I am not sure how to break down the logic here

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I think something must be missing here...

Comment: i edited the question. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a few small numbers and just count.  Try $m=2,n=7$ and a few other pairs, for example.  A more systematic approach:  How many numbers are in $[1,2,\dots n]?$  How many are in $[1,2,\dots m-1]?$  How many are left?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach.

Notice that we can write

$$\{1, 2, \ldots, m - 1, m, m + 1, \ldots n\} = \{1, 2, \ldots, m - 1\} \cup \{m, m + 1, \ldots n\}.$$

In other words, the set you're interested in has a nice relationship to two sets whose cardinalities you already know!

Answer (score 0):

When $n=m+1$ the number of elements is $2=m+1-m+1$. In the general case the number of elements is $n-m+1$